# Why clicking on my button don't alert range selected?

Tags: javascript

I' ve a button, so when user clicks it, it should alert range selected. If user didn't change the range selected (slider) default value 1 should be alerted.

Why is not alerting it?

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/abNQXLg

Error: it should only alert 1 value:

[image]

JS:

```
 $('#step_one_siguiente').on('click', function () {
        let val = this.value;
        alert($("#performance_options").prop("selected", true).text());
    });
```

Comment: @ishidex2 i was testing something, it should show JS also now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround that might be helpful.

```
let ranges = ['1080p','1440p','2k']

$('#step_one_siguiente').on('click', function () {
        var index = parseInt($('input').val()) - 1
        alert(ranges[index]);
    });
```

Comment: ty, but it alerts values from list, not values from range selected.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the way you use the syntax of the datalist is incorrect.
Values are not meant to be between the option tags but only in the value="" attribute.
However for this to work, the input value would need to match the list value, which is not compatible with a range control as the values you want are not a sequence.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Comment: Not my case, the values I want to alert are: 1, 2 or 3. Not the visual values users see, in backend I'll do some math. But don't know why I cannot alert those (1,2, 3) values.

Comment: if you want to alert 1, 2 and 3 then you should address the input element not the datalist : $('input[type="range"]').val()

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ibrahim question, I was able to come up with:

Apparently I don't have to search for a selected range, as it only returns the value of the selected one.

```
<script>

    $('#step_one_siguiente').on('click', function () {
        alert($('[type="range"]').val());
    });
</script>
```